# Get Percentage of Last X entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL(InnoDB). The first is an `employee` table. The other table is the `expense` table. For simplicity, the `employee` table contains just `id` and `first_name`. The `expense` table contains `id`, `employee_id`(foreign key), `amount_spent`, `budget`, and `created_time`. What I would like is a query that returns the percentage of their budget spent for the most recent X number of expense they've registered.

So given the employee table:

```
| id | first_name
-------------------
   1   alice
   2   bob
   3   mike
   4   sally
```

and the expense table:

```
| id | employee_id | amount_spent | budget | created_time
----------------------------------------------------------
   1        1             10          100       10/18
   2        1             50          100       10/19
   3        1             0           40        10/20
   4        2             5           20        10/22
   5        2             10          70        10/23
   6        2             75          100       10/24
   7        3             50          50        10/25
```

The query for the last 3 trips would return

```
|employee_id| first_name | percentage_spent |
--------------------------------------------
     1          alice           .2500 <----------(60/240)
     2          bob             .4736 <----------(90/190)
     3          mike            1.000 <----------(50/50)
```

The query for the last 2 trips would return

```
|employee_id| first_name | percentage_spent |
--------------------------------------------
     1          alice           .3571 <----------(50/140)
     2          bob             .5000 <----------(85/170)
     3          mike            1.000 <----------(50/50)
```

It would be nice if the query, as noted above, did not return any employees who have not registered any expenses (sally). Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll advise you to convert datatype of `created_time` as `DATETIME` in order to get accurate results.

As of now, I've assumed that most recent `id` indicates most recent **spents** as it's what sample data suggests.

Following query should work (didn't tested though):

```
select t2.employee_id,t1.first_name, 
  sum(t2.amount_spent)/sum(t2.budget) as percentage_spent
from employee t1
inner join 
(select temp.* from
        (select e.*,@num := if(@type = employee_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
                    @type := employee_id as dummy 
          from expense e
        order by employee_id,id desc) temp where temp.row_number <= 3   //write value of **n** here.
 ) t2
on t1.id = t2.employee_id               
group by t2.employee_id
;
```

[Click here for DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77ef1f/6/2)

Feel free to ask doubt(s), if you've any.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the datatype suggestion. Your query is returning `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: Please try the edited answer and check demo as well. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [mysql 8.0.2 and higher](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/) you might use window function for it.

```
 SELECT employee_id, first_name, sliding_sum_spent/sliding_sum_budget
 FROM
 (
  SELECT employee_id, first_name,
   SUM(amount_spent) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id
                        ORDER BY created_time
                        RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS sliding_sum_spent,
   SUM(budget) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id
                        ORDER BY created_time
                        RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS sliding_sum_budget,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id
                        ORDER BY created_time DESC) rn
  FROM expense
  JOIN employee On expense.employee_id = employee.id 
 ) t
 WHERE t.rn = 1
```

As mentioned by Harshil, order of row according to the `created_time` may be a problem, therefore, it would be better to use `date` date type.